# Looking for complete/good example of how to test Solana Smart contracts with Javascript (Jest)

Tags: javascript, testing

I'm looking for a good example or open-source project where I can see and learn how to test Solana smart contracts properly. I would also like to see how to test smart contracts using other programs such as `mpl_token_metadata`.

Thank you, Ladi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you find an open source program, look around, there is often a `/test/` folder nearby with tests of the program. I went to look for one at random: `https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/tree/master/candy-machine-core/js/test`

Here you have several tests for the Metaplex Candy Machine. However they are not made with Jest. The tests are often written with Mocha